# why is pointer address changing on return?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm working on homework, and I'm having a weird problem I'm hoping someone can help me out with. I have a function in the middle of my code:

```
Token scheme::addScheme(vector <Token> toAdd)
{

//Check if scheme is valid
Token answer = isSchemeValid(toAdd);
if (answer.retType() != "ok")
{
    return answer;
}

identifierList * arrow = new identifierList(&(toAdd.at(0)), NULL);
idList = arrow;

for (int i = 2; i < toAdd.size()-1; i++)
{
    (*arrow).id = &(toAdd.at(i));
    (*arrow).next= new identifierList(&(toAdd.at(0)), NULL);
    arrow = (*arrow).next;
}


*id = toAdd.at(0);
openParen = '(';
closeParen = ')';

return Token("ok", "ok", 0);
}
```

This code does everything I need it to do, except for the very end. It correctly sets all the variables to what I need them to be. Here's where it doesn't work: I run it step by step and I see that right after running the very last line
    return Token("ok", "ok", 0);
the values of idList change from legitimate values to crazy ones (for example, the first id in the idList's line number changes from 2 to -17891602.

this might make more sense if I post the header for what a identifierList and Token consist of:
Token:
    #pragma once
    using namespace std;
    #include 
    #include 
    #include 
    #include 
    #include "datalogProgram.h"

```
enum state {COMMA, PERIOD, Q_MARK, LEFT_PAREN, RIGHT_PAREN, COLON, COLON_DASH, MULTIPLY, ADD, SCHEMES, FACTS, RULES, QUERIES, ID, STRING, COMMENT, WHITESPACE, UNDEFINED, ENDOFFILE, START};

class Token
{
friend class datalogProgram;

public:
int lineNumber;
string type;
string value;

Token(string inType, string inValue, int inLineNum);
void route(state inState, string inValue, int inLineNum);
string retType();
string retValue();

//A list of a bunch of functions that don't matter here.
};
```

And an identifierList:

```
class identifierList
{
friend class scheme;
public:
Token * id;
identifierList * next;

identifierList(Token * inId, identifierList * inNext);
};
```

I don't get it- why are any variables changing when all I'm doing is returning from a function?

Comment: For readability purposes, prefer `arrow->id` over `(*arrow).id`.

Comment: You are passing the vector `toAdd` by value so you are receiving a copy of the vector and its content. Then you are taking address of vector elements: `&(toAdd.at(i))`. When you leave the function the copy of the vector is being destroyed and the pointers are no longer valid. Change the signature of `addScheme` to accept the vector by reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the vector toAdd is passed by value and not by reference. What happens is that the vector that you pass into the addScheme function is copied to stack.

Now, the statement (`&(toAdd.at(0)`) and similar statements take the reference of whatever is at position 0 in the vector. That means it returns a pointer to a location on the stack.

Once your function returns, the stack is cleared and the pointer to the location on the stack contains garbage.

To fix this either pass the vector by reference, or better avoid (`&(toAdd.at(0)`) because this is a very weird contract and will probably never work as you expect.

Comment: David- that was genuinely the most helpful thing I have ever read to answer my question, and the first answer I have every seen that 100 % answered my question- not just to help me with my homework, but to help me learn. Thank you very much!

Comment: Oh- right- Alon. I see now that David just edited it. Sorry- still a Stack Overflow noobie. Thanks!